# Mosquitto MQTT Disk Read Spike

Tags: php, laravel, mqtt, mosquitto

I've got an issue with one of our MQTT brokers running Mosquitto. Where there is a consistent increase in disk usage at a seemingly random time, until it reaches an equilibrium of about 50MB/s read (Shown in graph bellow).

This also causes a secondary issue with our PHP server (Laravel, PHP:7.4 running php-mqtt/client: v1.1.0), where once a connection issue occurs PHP CPU spikes to 100% until the broker is restarted and then PHP server is restarted (From testing must be in that order, else problem still persists). MQTT messages are broadcast on all Laravel jobs as part of a queue monitoring system. A note during this PHP issues, connections to the broker slowly increase, I assume this is just due to the broker holding them open but too slow to process them.

At a guess it might be something like QoS >0 messages stacking up on the broker causing excessive disk usage. Though I can't confirm this and would expect high disk write instead of read. I've checked for network bottlenecks and other potential causes but nothing found so far.

Currently at a loss as to what could cause this issue as 99% of the time the broker operates normally and there is nothing we know of that would trigger this consistent increase in disk I/O. Issue also occurred several weeks ago but at a different time of day.

##### Broker is running on a GCE Instance with the following specs:

- CPU: 2 vCPUs (E2 : Intel Broadwell)
- Memory: 4 GB
- Disk: 250GB (Max Throughput: 70MB/s)
- OS: Container-Optimized OS, 89

#### Broker disk monitoring

Normal throughput is what is seen before 1:30am
[image: Mosquitto Disk Throughput]

#### Broker network traffic

Network traffic is within the norms for this time of day. Dropped between 5:30 and 6:30 due to us trying to fix the issue.
[image]

#### Broker CPU

Never seems to reach 100% but could be due to high frequency spikes that the monitoring is averaging.
[image]

#### PHP Server CPU

Note CPU does not spike for serval hours after broker shows signs of a problem.
[image]

#### Mosquitto Version

Official Docker Container: `eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.14`

#### Mosquitto Config

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
protocol mqtt

listener 9001 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.passwd
acl_file /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.acl
```

#### Normal Traffic

Messages: ~1000 per minute throughput on the broker

PHP server only publishes short-lived messages with the following config:

```
QoS: 1
Retain: 0
Timeout: 1
```

#### Dump of some $SYS topics as of now:

```
$SYS/broker/version: "mosquitto version 1.6.14"
$SYS/broker/uptime: "23529 seconds"
$SYS/broker/messages/stored: "93" // Remained stable since monitoring
$SYS/broker/messages/received: "895858"
$SYS/broker/messages/sent: "1405546"
$SYS/broker/retained messages/count: "93" // Remained stable since monitoring
$SYS/broker/clients/total: "122078"
$SYS/broker/clients/inactive: "121984"
$SYS/broker/clients/disconnected: "121984"
$SYS/broker/clients/active: "94"
$SYS/broker/clients/connected: "94"
$SYS/broker/clients/maximum: "122078"
$SYS/broker/subscriptions/count: "393"
```

In the process of adding monitoring to these, gather data if the issue occurs again.

Comment: Please provide details of your mosquitto configuration (i.e. `mosquitto.conf`) and usage (how many subscribers, message volume, average size etc). It may be useful to monitor `$SYS/broker/messages/received`, `$SYS/broker/messages/inflight`, `$SYS/broker/retained messages/count` etc to provide you with data on message flows during the time you are experiencing issues.

Comment: It would be handy to know what version you're running, and whether you're using persistence, websockets, or an authentication plugin. The only time there is any `read` in the core broker is at startup, if persistence is enabled, and if you're using websockets and hosting files over http with it. If you're using an authentication plugin then it's possible it could be that, it depends.

Comment: Updated question with some extra information. Something I didn't notice before is the broker is log a lot of `Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting. "` messages. Happening basically all the time, so will try and find this client/s to remove or fix.

Comment: There's nothing in the configuration to worry about. The $SYS metrics you have look pretty modest as well, with one exception: `$SYS/broker/clients/disconnected`. This is "clients that have connected with clean session set to false, then disconnected". I'm taking a stab in the dark that you have a client that connects with clean session set to false that also uses a random client id. Even if it's not related to your problem it's worth clearing that up.

Comment: `Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.` - that probably just means the client disconnected without sending a DISCONNECT, no big deal if you're expecting lots of short lived connections. Version 2.0 does a better job with those messages if you wanted to investigate them.

Comment: Added monitoring for $SYS topic, and I will track down those clients, but thank you.

Comment: The only thing which comes to my mind is that because of the short-lived connections, you are burning through available sockets too fast and your disconnected sockets are in a `TIME_WAIT` state. Combined with receiving clients without clean session, this could explain why the broker is persisting so much. Are you opening a new connection to the broker for each queue job and do you have good reason to do so? And do you really need QoS 1 for the (probably nice-to-have) monitoring or would QoS as best-effort be fine as well?